# This REST activity is not configured. Configure all activities before activating

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity, marketingcloudapi

Trying to configure a custom activity on my journey builder. I hosted it on heroku and used github. Everything seems to be under the recommended sintaxt (config.json, etc) but when i try to active the journey builder this error occurs:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i needed to click on done first on my custom activity before i could validate. and activate journey builder